# Select Dropdown not displaying $scope value in model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've used angular plenty of times, but can't seem to spot the issue I'm getting:

I pass through an ID like so as a clickable link within a repeater:

```
<td data-title="'Company Name'" sortable="'CompanyName'"><a ui-sref="Locations({company_id: row.CompanyID})">{{row.CompanyName}}</a> </td>
```

The value is correctly passed through and received by the relevant controller I use a query string service to get the relevant filters. The console.log correctly shows the correct value. However, it is not selecting the relevant value within the select dropdown:

```
angular.module('app').controller("LocationsController", ['$timeout',  
'$scope', '$http', 'QueryStringService', 'NgTableParams', '$location', 
function ($timeout, $scope, $http, QueryStringService, NgTableParams, 
$location) {
var default_filters = { location_name: "", address_1: "", company_id: "" };
$scope.filterBy = QueryStringService.getFilters(jQuery.extend(true, {}, default_filters));

console.log($scope.filterBy.company_id);
}


// Displayed on relevant view
<select ng-model="filterBy.company_id" ng-options="option.CompanyID as option.CompanyName for option in companies" class="form-control form-control-query">
    <option value="">All</option>
</select>
```

Can anyone notice anything?

Comment: Is the `select` in another page of your app?

Comment: Yes it is, the select brings all correct values it just doesn't select the correct choice according to the value brought through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are facing a controller scope issue:
You are setting a variable in a controller **instance**, and trying to get it from **another instance**.

The fact is that a controller is instancied for each page, even if it is the same controller name (that may be confusing).

You should use a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) to store this variable (for example your `QueryStringService`), and access it from your other page.

---

Here is a [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/wt0n049p/1/).

Comment: I've used this way of setting values before and it's always worked up until now...